# Get current location on Apple Maps

Tags: iphone

I want to make a function that get current location on Apple Maps at maximum zoom level and then auto take a photo from this part

I searched on google but most of result is use Google Map. But I need do it on Apple Map.
Explain to me how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `delegate` method and add this `mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;` :

And then add this to easily set the zoom level just copy the `MKMapView-ZoomLevel.h` and `.m` :

[MKMapView Zoom Level](https://github.com/leviathan/MKMapView-Zoom-Levels)

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    [mapView setCenterCoordinate:userLocation.coordinate zoomLevel:20 animated:NO];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mapView.bounds.size, mapView.opaque, 0.0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [mapView.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   //save to Photo Album
     UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImagePNGRepresentation(image), nil, nil, nil);
}
```

Comment: How about take a snapshot of this. Can you give me an example code

Comment: the snapshot is took with  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mapView.bounds.size, mapView.opaque, 0.0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [mapView.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); and you can do whatever you want with the image.

Comment: What if I don't use mapview, just tap a button and all things are do at background then show a photo in imageview?

Comment: You have to be specific in what you want, you have all you need there, you can render any layer you need and use the image as you please.

Comment: [mapView setCenterCoordinate:userLocation.coordinate zoomLevel:20 animated:NO]; This methods is not exsited

Comment: I've given you a link to the files you need to have inside the project so you can use the zoom. Check my answer.

Comment: Check the method after you use the MkMapView+ZoomLevel.h , you should just copy the files and just import that , no additional things need to be done , just call the method.

Comment: I made it. I'm very appreciate